# Get multiple file data information after upload success codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

When I upload multiple images I would like to be able to display each file name.

**I can upload the file fine in to the upload folder**, but when I try to get the multiple file_name data it shows error below.

I get this error below

> Severity: Warning Message: Illegal string offset 'file_name' Filename:
>   page/Page_add.php Line Number: 110

Which is here in success part of upload function

```
$upload_info = $this->upload->data();

foreach ($upload_info as $upload_data) {
    echo $upload_data['file_name']; // Line 110
}
```

**Do upload function**

```
public function do_upload() {
    $directory = FCPATH . 'uploads/';

    if (is_dir($directory)) {

        foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $value) {

            if ($value['name'] != '') {

                $this->load->library('upload');

                $this->upload->initialize($this->do_upload_options());

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {

                    $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());

                    return FALSE;

                } else {

                    $upload_info = $this->upload->data();

                    foreach ($upload_info as $upload_data) {
                        echo $upload_data['file_name'];
                    }


                }

            }
        }

    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', 'Cannot Find Directory' .' '. $directory);

        return FALSE;

    }
}

public function do_upload_options() {
    $config = array();

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '30000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';

    return $config;
}
```

Each field name has its own name="" example name="fileupload_extra_image0" the number at the end is automatically generated

Vardump

```
array(2) { ["fileupload_extra_image0"]=> array(14) { ["file_name"]=> string(17) "ci_logo_flame.jpg" ["file_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["file_path"]=> string(49) "C:/Xampp/htdocs/riwakawebsitedesigns-cms/uploads/" ["full_path"]=> string(66) "C:/Xampp/htdocs/riwakawebsitedesigns-cms/uploads/ci_logo_flame.jpg" ["raw_name"]=> string(13) "ci_logo_flame" ["orig_name"]=> string(17) "ci_logo_flame.jpg" ["client_name"]=> string(17) "ci_logo_flame.jpg" ["file_ext"]=> string(4) ".jpg" ["file_size"]=> float(3.61) ["is_image"]=> bool(true) ["image_width"]=> int(100) ["image_height"]=> int(100) ["image_type"]=> string(4) "jpeg" ["image_size_str"]=> string(24) "width="100" height="100"" } ["fileupload_extra_image1"]=> array(14) { ["file_name"]=> string(10) "family.png" ["file_type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["file_path"]=> string(49) "C:/Xampp/htdocs/riwakawebsitedesigns-cms/uploads/" ["full_path"]=> string(59) "C:/Xampp/htdocs/riwakawebsitedesigns-cms/uploads/family.png" ["raw_name"]=> string(6) "family" ["orig_name"]=> string(10) "family.png" ["client_name"]=> string(10) "family.png" ["file_ext"]=> string(4) ".png" ["file_size"]=> float(828.1) ["is_image"]=> bool(true) ["image_width"]=> int(670) ["image_height"]=> int(450) ["image_type"]=> string(3) "png" ["image_size_str"]=> string(24) "width="670" height="450"" } }
```

Comment: Try without second foreach loop. In first loop you already separate process for every file.

Comment: @Tpojka It only returns the first filename. Each input file has its own name example name="file-upload1" name="file-upload2" name="file-upload3" the numbers are created automatic

Comment: `$upload_info[$field_name] = $this->upload->data();`

Comment: I did `$upload_info[$field_name] = $this->upload->data(); and `echo $upload_info[$field_name]['file_name'];` Still only return first file info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function do_upload() 
{
    $directory = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    $upload_info = [];//array();

    if (is_dir($directory)) {

        foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $value) {

            if ($value['name'] != '') {

                $this->load->library('upload');

                $this->upload->initialize($this->do_upload_options());

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {

                    $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());

                    return FALSE;//You would like to make better control here because first one is not file_name would break process

                } else {

                    $upload_info[$field_name] = $this->upload->data();

                }
            }
        }

        if ( count($upload_info) > 0 ) {
            foreach ($upload_info as $upload_data) {
                echo $upload_data['file_name'];
            }
        }

    } else {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload', 'Cannot Find Directory' .' '. $directory);

        return FALSE;

    }
}

public function do_upload_options() 
{
    $config = array();

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '30000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';

    return $config;
}
```

Comment: Displays it twice ci_logo_flame.jpg
family.png
ci_logo_flame.jpg
family.png

Comment: What do you get for `var_dump($upload_info); exit;` just before output - before If (count) I added?

Comment: I added the var dump to the main post

Comment: What is result? There should be answer of duplicating output.